# `npm install --force` lockfile not being respected by dockerfile build?

Tags: docker, npm

This is confusing so I apologize if I don't word this sufficiently well.

Essentially, I'm leveraging `npm`'s `--force` flag to bypass a conflicting peer-dependency error with `npm@8`. Subsequent `npm install` s of the dependencies complete without any errors. When attempting to install dependencies via docker, however, the original error returns.

So, originally:

1. encounter error:

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
...
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

2. bypass via `npm install --force`
3. subsequent `npm install`s work without issue in new local environments (e.g. clone into new dir, run `npm install`)

However, attempting to `npm install` or `npm ci` (`npm ci` ensures a lockfile already exists) in a docker build continues throws the original error:

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
...
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Which, to me, suggests the lockfile isn't being respected. But we know it exists because otherwise `npm ci` would error.

Does anyone have an idea as to why this might be the case?

Dockerfile I'm testing with:

```
# // Dockerfile

# ==== CONFIGURE =====
# Use a Node 16 base image
FROM node:16-alpine 
# Set the working directory to /app inside the container
WORKDIR /app
# Copy app files
COPY package-lock.json .
RUN echo $(ls)
# ==== BUILD =====
# Install dependencies (npm ci makes sure the exact versions in the lockfile gets installed)
RUN npm ci 

# Build the app
RUN npm run build
# ==== RUN =======
# Set the env to "production"
ENV NODE_ENV production
# Expose the port on which the app will be running (3000 is the default that `serve` uses)
EXPOSE 3000
# Start the app
CMD [ "npx", "serve", "build" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Local npm is v8.1, docker npm is v8.19. Seems they introduced a breaking change at some point between those two versions.

From [official docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-ci):

> NOTE: If you create your package-lock.json file by running npm install with flags that can affect the shape of your dependency tree, such as --legacy-peer-deps or --install-links, you must provide the same flags to npm ci or you are likely to encounter errors. An easy way to do this is to run, for example, npm config set legacy-peer-deps=true --location=project and commit the .npmrc file to your repo.